# 'Error loading path' with 'url' in createWindow

Tags: model-view-controller, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile, titanium-mobile

I have this code in `app.js`:

```
var login = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    url: 'controllers/loginController.js'
});

login.open();
```

In the Titanium documentation, it says this about the `url` property:

> Windows can be loaded from another JavaScript file by specifying the
>   property url, referencing a file relative to your application
>   Resources folder.

My `controllers` folder is inside the `Resources`folder. I doublechecked :)!

I was following the steps here:

http://blog.scottmontgomerie.com/01/mvc-in-appcelerator/

In his example project, he does the same.

However, I always get the following error message:

> ```
> [ERROR] error loading path: /Users/mobiel/Library/Application Support/iPhone
> ```
>
> Simulator/5.0/Applications/3DD8FFEF-4DD7-437E-8AE5-6851750FA0F8/teamTaskManager.app/Resources/controllers/loginController.js,
>   Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The operation couldn’t be
>   completed. (Cocoa error 260.)" UserInfo=0xa385b60
>   {NSFilePath=/Users/mobiel/Library/Application Support/iPhone
>   Simulator/5.0/Applications/3DD8FFEF-4DD7-437E-8AE5-6851750FA0F8/teamTaskManager.app/Resources/controllers/loginController.js,
>   NSUnderlyingError=0xa385aa0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. No
>   such file or directory"}

Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just an advice, you shouldn't load windows with the url property cause it creates a new js context. Since SDK 1.8 appcelerator been encouring their developers to use commonjs modules. You can see here ( http://github.com/appcelerator/Documentation-Examples/tree/master/commonjsExample ) a project example using commonjs. And this week there will be some presentations about titanium best pratices and they will probably give some new code examples using commonjs modules.

Comment: It might be hard to begin with commonjs modules, but believe me you will get a much cleaner code and easier to maintain. You can also check this: https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/CommonJS+Modules+in+Titanium and http://vimeopro.com/appcelerator/forging-titanium/video/27447911

Comment: Thanks. I'll definitely check those links :)

Comment: If you have 1.8+ thats suppose to work. January 11 there will be a best pratices webminar, probably they will give some tips about commonjs modules. http://developer.appcelerator.com/blog/2012/01/titanium-week-starts-today.html

Comment: It worked, after I deleted my build folder. Thanks. I'll make sure to check the best practices stuff!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by deleting the `build` folder from my project directory and re-building the project.

:|

Comment: I don't know if thats the case, but if you deploy your application to device and then you try to debug it in the simulator (or vice-versa) you will need to do a clean or you will get these type of problems (at least for iOS).